# Why DataGrid doesn't display sample design-time data?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I'm trying to load some sample data into my `UserControl` to work at design time.

It's a Sale that has associated a collection of OrderItems and a Number:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MiPaladar.SampleData
{
    public class SampleSale
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }        

        public ObservableCollection<SampleLineItem> OrderItems { get; set; }              
    }
}
```

The problem is the `TextBox` bound to the `Number` property shows it just fine, but the `DataGrid` bound to the collection of `OrderItems` is empty, not showing the items. Why not?

This the `SampleLineItem` class:

```
namespace MiPaladar.SampleData
{
    public class SampleLineItem
    {
        public float Quantity { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the `SampleSaleData.xaml`:

```
<local:SampleSale xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiPaladar.SampleData" 
                  Number="78" >
    <local:SampleSale.OrderItems>
    <local:SampleLineItem Quantity="1" Price="3.5"/>
    <local:SampleLineItem Quantity="2" Price="7"/>
    <local:SampleLineItem Quantity="1" Price="8"/>
</local:SampleSale.OrderItems>
```

Finally my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MiPaladar.Views.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              

         mc:Ignorable="d" 

         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >

<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/SampleSaleData.xaml}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Order Number:"  Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5" Text="{Binding Number}"/>
    </StackPanel>        

    <!--Orderitems-->
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderItems}"
              Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" >

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price, StringFormat=c}" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>        

</Grid>
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Found it!

just had to initialize the OrderItems collection in code. When you create collections in XAML, the new items are added to the collection via the Add() method. XAML doesn't create a new collection.

So, just this little modification:

    ObservableCollection<SampleLineItem> orderItems  = ObservableCollection<SampleLineItem>();  

    public ObservableCollection<SampleLineItem> OrderItems
    {
        get { return orderItems; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: never mind -- you beat me to it; although I'm curious if my change would have worked as well.

I think there should be a `</local:SampleSale >` at the end of `SampleSaleData.xaml`.